# Objective-c IOS arm64 method swizzling fail to call original method

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, arm64, method-swizzling

I use standard method swizzling on ARMv7 IOS devices and it works perfect to me.

But when I compile my code for arm64 - it fails to call original method from new method

Main purpose of my swizzling - to use parameter from internal method of my application in another method.

I have original method `-(void)insertdata:(id)text` and I want to change it on `-(void)patchedCall:(id)text` and call original method in new method.

Code:

```
static IMP sOriginalImp = NULL;

@interface TextOverrides: NSObject
+(void)load;
-(void)patchedinsert:(id)text;
@end

@implementation TextOverrides

+(void)load
{
    //Get Implementation of original method

    Class originalClass = NSClassFromString(@"DataViewController");
    Method originalMeth = class_getInstanceMethod(originalClass, @selector(insertdata:));

    //Save original method implementation
    sOriginalImp = method_getImplementation(originalMeth);

    // Get implementation of replacement method
    Method replacementMeth = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"TextOverrides"), @selector(patchedCall:));

    //Replace methods
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMeth, replacementMeth);
}

-(void)patchedCall:(id)text
{
    @synchronized(self){
        //Call of original method that we save
        sOriginalImp(self, @selector(insertdata:), text);

        //Make our code for argument "text"
        printf("Here is data%s\n", [text UTF8String]);
    }
}

@end
```

Code fails on calling original method on arm64 architecture:

```
//Call of original method that we save
sOriginalImp(self, @selector(insertdata:), text);
```

How can I improve my code to work both on armv7 and arm64?

Answer (score 2):

With the discussion on https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger/issues/84 I think the gist is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW22 and the fact that `IMP` is defined as a variadic function and you call it with fixed arguments. In my case, casting the function pointer to the real signature fixed the crash. I believe in your case, something like

```
//Call of original method that we save
((void(*)(id, SEL, id))ssOriginalImp)(self, @selector(insertdata:), text);
```

could fix the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I dont’t think the loading order of all classes are specified somewhere. So it might be that the `TextOverrides` class is loaded before `DataViewController` on arm64, but not on armv7. See https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html

To make it stable you should only swizzle methods in a category +load method. Eg:

```
@interface DataViewController (TextOverrides)
+(void)load;
-(void)patchedinsert:(id)text;
@end

@implementation DataViewController (TextOverrides)

+(void)load
{
    // swizzle here
}
...
```

Comment: I use this code as Dynamic Library and "DataViewController" couldn't be used in such way.
I debug code in runtime - DataViewController class methods are loaded earlier and swizzling work - methods are changed and if we don't call original method - everything works fine.
But when we call it - it can't find selector.